# Does this matrix of ones and zeros have a nonzero maximal minor?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Choose $n\ge 5$. We define a ${n\choose 3}\times {n\choose 2}$ matrix $A$ in the following way:

Each row is identified with a triplet $\{i,j,k\}$ and each column identified with a pair $\{s,t\}$.
Define $A_{\{i,j,k\},\{s,t\}}=1$ if $\{s,t\}\subseteq \{i,j,k\}$ and zero otherwise.

Does $A$ have a nonzero maximal minor?

Edit: the determinant of the square case $n=5$ is $-48$.

Comment: I think that a lot is known about the incidence matrices of the $r$-faces of the $n$-simplex (which I have for the moment forgotten!) I seem to recall that you get information by looking at the sequence of maps carrying the vertex-space to the edge-space to the face-space etc etc (and the maps coming down as well).

Comment: By maximal minor do you mean the determinant of a submatrix of size ${n \choose 2} \times {n \choose 2}$?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we start, recall that for any real matrix $X$ the products $X^{T}X$ and $XX^{T}$ are symmetric and so diagonalisable; and that their non-zero eigenvalues coincide, even having the same multiplicities.

Recall also that if $A$ and $B$ are sets of size $r$ then $|A\cup B|=r+1$ if and only if $|A\cap B|=r-1$.

Assume throughout that $n>2r$.

Let $V_r$ denote the real vector space spanned by the $r$-subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$; and let $D_r:V_r\to V_{r+1}$ be the linear map that carries each $r$-subset to the sum of the $(r+1)$-subsets which it lies in. Our intention is to show that $D_r$ has rank $n \choose r$.

Consider the map $D_r^{T} D_r$; the $(R_1,R_2)$ entry is precisely the number of $(r+1)$-subsets containing both $R_1$ and $R_2$. Similarly  the $(R_1,R_2)$ entry of $D_{r-1} D_{r-1}^{T}$ is precisely the number of $(r-1)$-subsets contained in both $R_1$ and $R_2$.

Note that if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are distinct $r$-subsets then one of two things happens. Either (i) there exists no $(r+1)$ subset containing both $R_1$ and $R_2$, because $R_1\cup R_2$ is too large, and in this case there is no common $(r-1)$ subset, because $R_1\cap R_2$ is too small; or else (ii) $|R_1\cup R_2|=r+1$ and $|R_1\cap R_2|=r-1$, and so $R_1$ and $R_2$ lie in exactly one $(r+1)$-subset and contain exactly one $(r-1)$-subset.

When $R_1=R_2$ then $R_1$ lies in $(n-r)$ subsets of size $(r+1)$, and contains $r$ subsets of size $(r-1)$.

Putting these together we see that $D_r^{T} D_r=D_{r-1} D_{r-1}^{T}+(n-2r)I$.

We can now build up the eigenvalues of the $D_r^{T} D_r$ recursively.

(i) The eigenvalue of $D_0^{T} D_0$ is $n$ with multiplicity $n\choose 0$.

(ii) Hence the eigenvalues of $D_0 D_0^{T}$ are $n$ with multiplicity $n\choose 0$ and $0$ with multiplicity 
${n\choose 1} -  {n\choose 0}$.

(iii) Hence the eigenvalues of $D_1^{T} D_1$ are $2n-2$ with multiplicity $n\choose 0$ and $n-2$ with multiplicity 
${n\choose 1} -  {n\choose 0}$.

(iv) Hence the eigenvalues of $D_1 D_1^{T}$ are $2n-2$ with multiplicity $n\choose 0$,  $n-2$ with multiplicity 
${n\choose 1} -  {n\choose 0}$ and $0$ with multiplicity 
${n\choose 2} -  {n\choose 1}$.

(v) Hence the eigenvalues of $D_2^{T} D_2$ are $3n-6$ with multiplicity $n\choose 0$,  $2n-6$ with multiplicity 
${n\choose 1} -  {n\choose 0}$ and $n-4$ with multiplicity 
${n\choose 2} -  {n\choose 1}$.

It is now clear that $D_2^{T} D_2$ is non-singular and so $D_2$ is of full rank.

I dedicate this answer to the memory of [Dr Jack Hammersley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hammersley) : he set an undergraduate examination question on mean recurrence times of random walks on some highly symmetric graphs which inspired my interest in problems like this.

Comment: This is a great answer! I was wondering how showing that the matrix is nonsingular says anything about its maximal minors. If it was square then if every minor is zero the inverse matrix would be zero, which is a contradiction, but this matrix is not square. How do we conclude that the matrix has a nonzero maximal minor?

Comment: @nole Two possible answers: (i) set theory, $fg$ is 1-1 onto implies $f$ is onto and $g$ is 1-1 (ii) determinant theory, the $k\times k$ minors of $XY$ are sums of products of $k\times k$ minors of $X$ with $k\times k$ minors of $Y$.